# What software offer hand-drawn style capabilities?

Tags: style-identification

I have come across the below drawing.

[image]

Comment: Any? All? what specifically is your question, can you [edit] to add more details?

Comment: Related: https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3819/what-are-the-requirements-for-software-identification-or-related-questions

Comment: I expected a more specific style, I expect this'll get closed as too broad since "hand-drawn" can be done in pretty much anything

Comment: all one really needs is notepad or any other text editor. though seriously you should add a bit more specificity.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any current raster image software has it. Gimp, Krita, Ps, FireAlpaca, MediBang, MyPaint, PaintNet, PaintToolSAI and so.

Any decent vector graphic program has it. Illustrator, CorelDraw, AfinityDesign or Inkscape.

A lot of animation software has it.

Even Blender, which is mainly a 3D program has it.

Normally they call this tool "brush".

---

You can use your mouse, but probably it is more useful to have a drawing tablet.

What you need to control is the hardness of the brush and avoid transparencies.

---

But for that specific composition, You should stick to a vector-based program. Some of the assets are repetitions of the same element, so it will be easier to handle.

Also, you need to find some hand-drawn style fonts that fit the specific style.

Comment: even mathematica mainly a math application has this, even after effects mainly a motion graphics software has this, even rhino mainly a CAD application has this.What else? Notepad!

Answer (score 1):

These look like vector graphics, so I would use vector software for this. Something like Adobe Illustrator (not free), or Inkscape (free).

It's easy to draw freehand with the pencil tool in both of these applications. If you don't get it quite right, the lines are Bézier paths which can easily be adjusted until you get the look you want. Find a nice handwriting font for the text.

An example of similar graphics made in Inkscape by hand, in a couple of minutes. I drew these with an ordinary mouse, nothing fancy, no stylus/graphics tablet or anything like that.

[image]